# VSTO Add-in not loading. Looks like VSTO itself is not loading?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I have an Outlook Add-in.  In Outlook 2016 (Office 365 desktop version) it will not load.  32 bit Office install on Windows 10 64 bit. It appears that the VSTO runtime itself is not loading.  The add-in does not appear.  It doesn't appear in the disabled add-ins, nor in the Manage Add-ins anywhere to be enabled.

The add-in registry entry for being always enabled is correctly added.  I have verified that the correct .NET version and the VSTO runtime are all installed.  I have set

```
VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS 0
VSTO_LOGALERTS 1
```

and receive no data back from them.

I have also verified that the registry keys are correct.  `LoadBehavior` is set to 3 and `Manifest` is pointing to the correctly installed file.

What is even more curious is that it did load at one point and worked fine, but seemingly all of a sudden it will not.

Has anyone run into this or know anything I can check to see what is going on?

Comment: Did you check the add-in settings (i.e. `LoadBehavior`) in both HKLM and HKCU? Does the add-in appear under *File > Options > Add-ins*? How is it listed there?

Comment: It is not listed there, which is what it is baffling to me.  The addin registry keys appear under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyAddin and are correct.  Do they need to be in the user hive as well?  It is installed in Program Files(x86)

Comment: How about *File > Slow and Disabled COM Add-ins*?

Comment: It is not there either.  I have the value at 1 for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList\MyAddin`  as well.  What is baffling me is that it did work for a couple of days and now it does not.   I'm looking into Outlook changes during that time frame, like an update or something that might have caused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event anyone runs into this, here are the steps used to solve the problem for me.

- Uninstall my add-in
- Uninstall the VSTO runtime
- Uninstall Outlook, including any non-2016 components if any remain
- Reinstall Outlook (2016 should have the run time)
- Reinstall the add-in

It's a pain, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with VSTO Add-In for Word, the situation was similar:

- Registry keys were correctly set
- Add-In not visible in COM add-in in Word (even not visible in the disabled ones)

What I did to fix this issue:

- Re-install Office